# file data not getting passed on js drop event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, event-handling

I have several methods in a class.
Class instances are being dynamically created.
One of the instances adds an event listener to the 'drop' event. That drop event listener function is supposed to pass the image data to `handleDrop()` in the class instance, but I'm getting `cannot read property 'dataTransfer' of undefined` at the `dt = e.dataTransfer,` line of the handler function.

I'm trying to follow https://soshace.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-drag-and-drop-image-uploading-with-pure-javascript/

data listener code

```
    canvasWrapper.addEventListener('drop', canvasContext.preventDefault, false);
    canvasWrapper.addEventListener('drop', function () {
        canvasContext.handleDrop(this.event), false;

    });
```

handler function

```
handleDrop(e) {
    let dt;
    console.log('we have a drop');
    dt = e.dataTransfer,
        console.log('dt', dt);
    files = dt.files;
```

Complete code is at https://github.com/tnewhook/CartoonBuilder/blob/master/cartoonBuilder.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple: I needed to combine the two lines in `handleDrop()` into `files = e.dataTransfer.files,`. For some reason it liked the single var instead of two.